# When I right click on jquery ui spinner it increments automatically non-stop. Any way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

This issue is experienced only in Linux and Mac OS. It seems to be a jQuery spinner bug.

The spinner under the link has the bug too:

https://jqueryui.com/spinner/

```
<input class="spinner"/>
$(".spinner").spinner("value",1);
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I'm using the basic spinner plugin. No extra code.

Comment: so you have simply included the lib??? ...... dude, please post your code

Comment: You can at least post some images or gifs??

Comment: @Caleb no, images and gifs are not recommended

Comment: @reflexgravity Unable to replicate in FF on Linux. Please provide more steps to replicate the issue. Does this happen in Chrome? FF? Safari? Be more specific.

Comment: It happens on Chrome.

Comment: Unable to replicate in Chrome on MacOS (I get the context menu when right clicking, just like any other DOM element.)

Comment: Ah, never mind, now I see it.  If I right-click *on the increment button*, not the spinner field, then it increments continuously (just like holding the mouse down continuously.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem only exists when the user right-clicks on the increment/decrement buttons (the context menu appears to interfere with the mouse events that `spinner()` expects.)

You can work around this by disabling the context menu for those buttons only:

```js
$('.spinme').spinner();

// disable right-click on the increment/decrement buttons
// You'll need to do this after the spinner is instantiated,
// so the buttons already exist when you bind this event to them.  
// Or use delegated events.
$('#nomenu .ui-spinner-button').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Default behavior:<br>
  <input class="spinme">
</div>
<br>
<div id="nomenu">
  Context menu removed:<br>
  <input class="spinme">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this. But on safari, the spinner doesn't work if I disable the context-menu.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this bug adding `onfocus` attribute to the HTML.

```
<input class="ui-spinner" onfocus="this.blur()"/>
```

Comment: ...that would make it impossible for users to type data into the spinner.

Comment: The spinner doesn't need for values to be inserted. The user can use the incrementer and the decrementer to change the values.

Comment: Including a UI element (the input field) and then intentionally disabling it, with no visible indication that it's been disabled, is maybe not the *best* UI.  If you only want the user to be able to use the buttons, why use a spinner?

Comment: @DanielBeck Only the input functionality has been disabled. But the user can use the incrementer and decrementer to change the values. That is the primary function of a spinner. That's why I'm using a spinner.

Comment: Yes, the input functionality was what I was talking about.  "I only disabled half of the widget" is what you're saying, and I'm saying "then why include that half in the first place." I think this is a hack of a solution, and poor UI to boot, but hey, it's your site, do what you like